# Jinja2 Templates create extra space on empty tags

Tags: python, flask, whitespace, jinja2, removing-whitespace

```
{% block flashes %}
    <section class='flashes'>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                <ul>
                    {% for message in messages %}
                        <li>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Whenever the section tag is empty i see something like this in my HTML source-view or even chrome dev-tool

**Dev-tool**
[image]

---

**View Source**
[image]

---

if I remove the indents and extra white spaces the maintenance will be hard, is there any solution to this ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [whitespace control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control).

You should use `{%-` and `-%}` instead of `{%` and `%}`.

Comment: Thanks you mean on every thing? blocks , if, for , endif ... ?

Comment: @CameronA yes. if you want to strip all empty lines

Comment: Thanks man it worked